# How to interpret Instrument Leaks results

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

I could use some help interpreting results from the Instruments Leaks tool. This is for an iPhone app that I am writing. This is using XCode 4.2 and Instruments 4.2, if it makes a difference.

After running the tool, I get a list of leaked objects. When I examine the details of one these objects, it shows what I assume to be a history of what happened to the object. For example, it shows a sequence of: malloc, retain, release, retain, release, release. It also shows a resulting reference count of 0. See the picture for a screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

So my question is: why does Leaks think this is memory leak, and what do I need to do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the -dealloc method for your Waypoint and make sure it is calling [super dealloc].

Comment: You're great. That was the problem.